# Do we need volatile keyword and the mutex locks together for thread safety?

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, volatile

Having mutex locks for critical section says that more than one thread won't be able to ruin the critical section, but then why would we need the **volatile** variable for the same thing?

What would happen if there is no **volatile** word in the following code?

[image]

Comment: Java or C++ ? That does matter here.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Java (see 'Watch it!' block)

Comment: @HenkHolterman the book talks in java, but I would like to know about C++

Comment: @Diamondo25 - I saw that, but also the question tags.

Comment: `volatile` has a **totally different meaning** in Java and in C++.

Comment: **Double checked locking** is a failed concept in C++.

Comment: @DumbCoder, why? It works: http://mortoray.com/2012/02/28/double-checked-locking-why-doesnt-it-work-and-how-to-fix-it/

Comment: @edA-qa mort-ora-y - http://www.aristeia.com/Papers/DDJ_Jul_Aug_2004_revised.pdf

Comment: @DumbCoder, your article is outdated. You most certainly can implement double checked locking with C++11 and/or compiler extensions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The volatile keyword makes the double checked locking work correctly on 1.5 and later JVMs, see the [Under the new Java Memory Model](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html) section of that page.

If there was no volatile keyword there is a possibility of two instances being created on 1.5 and later JVMs. On pre-1.5 JVMs double checked locking is considered completely broken, and should not be used.

However, in the case of initialising a singleton, the use of double checked locking is usually  considered not worth it and a simple static initialisation will suffice. If you absolutely know the singleton will be initialised at some point by your application, then the lazy instantiation is redundant. Just go for:

```
private static Singleton s_instance = new Singleton()
```

or whatever the C++ equivalent is. Nice and safe!

As this question has ended up a rather tangled mess of Java & C++ please note, I am referring to Java above. In C++ there is no synchronized keyword, and volatile is not applicable to concurrency.

Comment: thanks, for information - now please talk about C++. Does all this happen there too?

Comment: @AnishaKaul: No. `volatile` in C++ has absolutely _nothing_ to do with multithreading (apart from on a few compilers which extend it to give it various memory ordering semantics). It is meant to be used for values that could be changed by something external to the program (such as a memory-mapped device).

Comment: But, hang on - the book is talking about Java! You want to know if the same code works in C++? While they are superficially similar, these are two completely different languages. C++ doesn't even have the `synchronized` keyword for a start. Did you mean to ask "How do I implement double checked locking in C++?" Sounds like a separate question to me...

Comment: @MalcolmSmith so synchronized is a keyword?? didn't know that - thought it to be a kind of sudocode.  "Did you mean to ask "How do I implement double checked locking in C++?" Sounds like a separate question to me" I assumed this code will work for C++ too. :( If we forget volatile will this work for c++ with mutex locks?

Comment: I'm afraid my C++ is not up to answering your question. But I think you can safely assume that this Java example is completely inapplicable to a C++ scenario. As I mentioned in my answer above - do you _really_ even need lazy instantiation via double checked locking? If you know this singleton needs to get made just go for `private static Singleton s_instance = new Singleton()` or whatever the C++ equivalent is. Nice and safe!

Comment: @MalcolmSmith Actually the book says that this method is lighter on performance as compared to the original method - that's why

Comment: Malcom, would you add the information about the C++ (volatile) bit in your "answer" so that I can select it.

Answer (score 3):

The `volatile` keyword does not provide any locking.

Its purpose is to prevent compiler optimizations that would 'cache' the value so that a thread might be checking out-of-date data.

Volatile is subtly different between languages and always a bit of a problem. Read your specs carefully and follow trusted examples.

Comment: thanks, but did you see the comment on that page with the star on its left.?

Comment: @AnishaKaul: Your book is talking about Java, this answer is talking about C++. `volatile` means something **completely different** in Java and C++, thus the difference between this answer and the book.